# Javascript - Center div horizontal and vertical with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, centering

I'm trying to center a div horizontally and verticlaly without knowing the height/width. I've achieved it within jquery but am struggling to convert it to pure js as I don't want dependancy.. any ideas?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(mt);
    $(window).resize(mt);
    function mt(){
    var contentLocked = $('.lockerPopup').outerHeight(); 
        marginTop = ( $(document).height() - contentLocked ) / 2;
        $('.lockerPopup').css({'top': marginTop});}
</script>
```

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: If you concern is that you don't know what margin to set just because you don't know height and width of the div, you can still use CSS to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.offsetWidth` and `.offsetHeight` to get the dimensions of your element and `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` for the dimensions of the window. The rest of the logic is pretty straight forward to center it using `.style.top` and `.style.left`.

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYjqWZ

Alternatively, if you want to center multiple things or you don't need it to be positioned absolutely, I would suggest looking into `flexbox` or use

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

in your CSS to stay away from JS entirely.

Comment: This makes it go off page like this:

Comment: Are you using the JS method or the CSS method?

Answer (score 0):

you can center by using left 50%; top 50% and -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,50%); (obviously add all of the other versions of webkit transform for cross-browser compatibility.

This will always center the div no matter what its width/height and parent container size.

Comment: did you add position:absolute?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need javascript for that, 
you can do it only using CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/gjah19y7/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="element"><p>test</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
.container {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:#CCC;
}

.element {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    color:#222;
}
```